# Error 1 while trying to create thumbnail from video using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, images

I'm hosting an imageboard and I'm trying to fix a problem where thumbnails wouldn't generate for uploaded videos. In the debug log I found an entry that says "Generating thumbnail with command `ffmpeg -i 'images/e4/e4bd5f87cfcb80f5ab2f3e3fdd927d9c' -vf scale="'if(gt(a,192/192),192,-1)':'if(gt(a,192/192),-1,192)'" -ss 00:00:00.0 -f image2 -vframes 1 'thumbs/e4/e4bd5f87cfcb80f5ab2f3e3fdd927d9c'`, returns 1". I assumed error 1 means that it couldn't find the file, so I changed the code so that it would point to the full path of the image, yet oddly it still gives error 1. Even stranger, executing the generated command after the edit, but in a command line, works just fine!

Full error (this is the one that runs fine when ran through a command line):

Generating thumbnail with command `ffmpeg -i '/opt/lampp/apps/images/images/e4/e4bd5f87cfcb80f5ab2f3e3fdd927d9c' -vf scale="'if(gt(a,192/192),192,-1)':'if(gt(a,192/192),-1,192)'" -ss 00:00:00.0 -f image2 -vframes 1 '/opt/lampp/apps/images/thumbs/e4/e4bd5f87cfcb80f5ab2f3e3fdd927d9c'`, returns 1

Comment: I don't see any error there. Can you run the command with the `-report` option and attach the actual error log from ffmpeg? And please also show the command line output from the command that runs fine.

Comment: @slhck I added the `-report` option to the command, but when the website attempts to generate a thumbnail and fails, the report file seems to be nonexistent. Running it in the terminal puts it in the working directory, where would that be for apache? I ran `find / -name "ffmpeg*"` to try to find it but only found the one that was made when I ran it in terminal. Here's the output for when it runs fine: https://pastebin.com/9Zdj4UFc

Comment: I tried using ffmpegthumbnailer with the least options, yet no joy...

"Generating thumbnail with command `ffmpegthumbnailer -i '/opt/lampp/apps/images/images/68/6899cde3c11150d52f0cbfb6c6348c55' -o '/opt/lampp/apps/images/thumbs/68/6899cde3c11150d52f0cbfb6c6348c55'`, returns 1"